# Finding causation in data with Conditional entropy

Tags: causality, entropy, information-theory

Conditional entropy [is defined here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy).  I was wondering about an algorithm to find causality between random variables.  In particular, I want to calculate $H(X|Y)$ and $H(Y|X)$ and make a guess as to causation given which is closer to 0.  Is this possible?

Comment: Your idea seems reminiscent of [transfer entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_entropy).

Comment: You may want to take a look at [information flow](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Information-Flows-in-Causal-Networks-Ay-Polani/cea9940860abc3dea72d9ebdbb699a9d885c0724) or [causal information gain](https://arxiv.org/abs/2309.07703) (disclaimer: I'm one of the authors of the second paper).